# Program to cut&save rectangles out of a scanned document

Tags: image-processing, scanning

I often use my scanner to scan multiple small receipts. I can fit 10 small receipts on a page. I'd like to save these receipts, each to a separate file. I can do this easily with copy and paste, but is there a program that makes this process faster?

**Update:** I'm on Windows 7, should have mentioned that.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: @Davidenko Windows 7, sorry I should have mentioned it in my question. Updated.

Comment: Related: [Photoshop solution in Any program that can automatically split photos in one scan?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/92815/34902), [Is there a software to automatically crop a scan of multiple images?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/16967/13586)

Comment: @IvanChau Thanks for the links. Spent 20 minutes now trying them and the solutions were useless for me. The Photoshop option is broken, the detection was way off. The autosplitter program had bad detection as well, and the interface is so clunky that it's probably slower than manually copy-pasting from a basic image editor.

Comment: @BarathVutukuri Thanks for the suggestion to try AutoSplitter just under my comment saying why I didn't like AutoSplitter :)

Comment: @RamRachum try this gimp script http://registry.gimp.org/node/22177

Comment: @BarathVutukuri I'm seeing that this script is fully automatic. This is a problem for me, I need to be able to go in and fix the crops when they're wrong.

Comment: @RamRachum Cool-RR ;) I will try to find more solutions for your problem :)

Comment: Related: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/16924/software-for-matching-rectangular-images-in-other-images-or-pdfs

Answer (score 4):

If you use a standard layout for them then you can do it from the command line with [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) - takes a little bit of playing around with the options but once you have got them you can use from a batch file.

Once you have got into imagemagick you can possibly use a coloured background for your scans - *say red* - that is unlikely to appear on your receipts and use the scripting language to split the file up based on where the background is showing - [Fred's Image Magic](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/) scripts is well worth a look.  There also is an example script [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/scripts/divide_vert) - in bash scripting that will split an image vertically as a starting point.

Imagemagick is free & multiplatform.

Comment: Command line doesn't help me, because the receipts are different sizes every time so I need to specify manually where to cut. Regarding the script, I'm looking for a ready solution, not something I'll have to tinker with. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to use [Gimp](http://www.gimp.org/), either manually as described below, or using the script [Divide Scanned Images](http://registry.gimp.org/node/22177)<sup>1</sup> <sup>2</sup> for automatic detection.

As it gives me better control, I would open the scanned image, and repeat following:

- Mark with rectangle a given receipt
- Copy, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> (or Cut, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>)
- Use *Edit > Paste As > New image*, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> <sup>3</sup>

*After* copying/cutting all receipts, I would close original image, and save each receipt with a proper name.

A variation of this is to do the following:

- Duplicate image, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>
- Mark rectangle with receipt
- Crop to selection, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
- Save, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>
- Close window, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> (returning to original image)

Note that the link provided from SuperUser, lists this example, the "Divide Scanned Images" script, and some other methods, including one using [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) which looks kind of interesting if you are into command line scripting.

<sub><sup>1</sup> [Can the Gimp split an image into multiple images?](https://superuser.com/questions/20081/can-the-gimp-split-an-image-into-multiple-images) from SuperUser SE</sub>
<sub><sup>2</sup> https://irfanview-forum.de/showthread.php?t=6781#post37213</sub>
<sub><sup>3</sup> Little uncertain on shortcuts as I use a Mac when writing this answer</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Lightshot](https://app.prntscr.com/en/index.html). You're able to size any rectangle you want on your screen. Lightshot also includes many features like drawing, copying selected area to the clipboard, or uploading the selected area to the cloud.

Comment: The fact it's a screenshot is a problem, I'd lose scan quality. But thanks for the link.